# How to copy debug assets for unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have an android library gradle project. And I need to copy some files to assets folder for robolectric unit tests.

To do it I've defined a copy task:

```
task copyDebugAssets(type: Copy)  {
    from "${projectDir}/somewhere"
    into "${buildDir}/intermediates/bundles/debug/assets"
}
```

but I can't add this task as a dependency for `processDebugResources` task:

```
processDebugResources.dependsOn copyDebugAssets
```

because of this error:

> Could not get unknown property 'processDebugResources' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

Now I have to manually execute this task before unit test:

```
./gradlew clean copyDebugAssets test
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The android plugin adds several tasks dynamically. Your `.dependsOn` line doesn't work because at the time gradle is trying to process this line, `processDebugResources` task yet available. You should tell gradle to add the dependency as soon as the upstream task is available:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
  if (task.name == 'processDebugResources') {
    task.dependsOn copyDebugAssets 
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works! What do you think, is it a correct way to copy assets with custom task, or maybe I shoud choose another approach?

Comment: I agree with @commonsware, changing your project setup to point to where you assets are, is better than copying.

Answer (score 3):

Why copy? Configure where the assets should be pulled from:

```
android {
    // other cool stuff here

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            assets.srcDirs = ['../testAssets']
        }
    }
}
```

(replacing `../testAssets` with a path to where the assets should come from)

I have used this successfully with `androidTest` for instrumentation testing. AFAIK, it should work for `test` or any other source set.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I've tried your config, but it was not successfull. Robolectric's `AssetManager` try to load assets from `./build/intermediates/bundles/<debug|release>/assets`, however this folder is always empty.